# Symfony 2 doctrine persist Parent entity from child

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, cascade, persist

I'm triying to update a parent entity, when I update a child entity, so when I call a child method, I call to the parent method, like this:

```
class Parent(){
    public function setUpdate($bool){
        $this->update = $bool;
    }
}

class Child(){
    public function setUpdate($bool){
        $this->update = $bool;
        $this->getParent()->setUpdate($bool); /*CALL PARENT METHOD*/
    }
}
```

The parent method is called, but when I make a persist over the Child Entity, the parent persist doesn't fire.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `the parent persist doesn't fire`. Is there a error message? Can you post the code of your entities. There is too much to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the cascade attribute on your entity mapping. For example:

```
class User
{
//...
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="user_id", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $parent;
//...
}
```

Take a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Comment: My parent has a lot of children, so the mappedBy and the cascade is in the parent entity (OneToMany), so this way, I can update children from the parent, but not viceversa, that is what I want to :(

Comment: In this case you don't need to persist child, just parent. you can do something like this: `$parent->getChildren()->add(new Child());` and then persist $parent

Comment: Maybe if you provide some of your code I can help you better.

Comment: I have my parent and my child created, so they are connecting and well saved in the DDBB. Now I want to change my child entity, for example, the name of my child. So I have a form to update the data of my child, but what I want that when I update mu child my parent save the date of update of his child. This way, when I make a preUpdate in the child, i call Child->getParent()->setModified(new \DateTime("now"); and this functions is called, but the parent is not persist :( It's clear now?? Thanks!!